# how to recover windows 10 after deleting the partition of ubuntu from dual boot pc

Tags: windows, ubuntu, boot

i deleted ubuntu partition from disk management in windows 10,then i type "bootrec.exe/fixmbr" in command prompt. after restarting the pc i got the black grub menu screen. how to solve this problem how to get my windows back.
few things about my pc..
My pc has already windows 10 installed so i never use flash drive in order to reinstall windows(in case of format).
My pc is booted in uefi mode for both windows and ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

you should also do

```
bootsect /nt60
```

If that doesn't work, from [here](http://linuxbsdos.com/2015/09/05/how-to-delete-grub-files-from-a-boot-efi-partition-in-windows-10/). Please don't blame me if you cannot boot after this!

- Run a cmd.exe process with administrator privileges
- Run diskpart
- Type: list disk then sel disk X where X is the drive your boot files
  reside on
- Type list vol to see all partitions (volumes) on the disk
- Select the EFI volume by typing: sel vol Y where Y is the SYSTEM
  volume (this is almost always the EFI partition)
- For convenience, assign a drive letter by typing: assign letter=Z:
  where Z is a free (unused) drive letter
- Type exit to leave disk part
- While still in the cmd prompt, type: Z: and hit enter, where Z was
  the drive letter you just created.
- Type dir to list directories on this mounted EFI partition
- If you are in the right place, you should see a directory called EFI
  Type cd EFI and then dir to list the child directories inside EFI
- Type rmdir /S ubuntu to delete the ubuntu boot directory